# How to make an object follow path and face the same direction as the other object

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, faces, constraints, path

I have an object that follows path. Path shrinkwrapped to bigger object. I want to make the object follow path while facing the same direction as the bigger objects surface, not intersect while following path.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, you can give a *Follow Path* constraint to your object with the curve as *Target*, then a *Shrinkwrap* constraint, with the surface as *Target*, enable the *Align to Normal* option and choose the right angle:

[image]

Here is what it gives:

[image]

Keep in mind that it will be the object's origin that will be taken into account by the *Shrinkwrap* so you may want to move the origin to the bottom of the object if you want it to stay on the surface of its target.